# gsutil - cp not processing each item in the pipeline

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a small Powershell script which will copy a list of files matching a specific condition to a specified GCP Storage Bucket. I have gotten this far:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object { $_.psiscontainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $Age } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | ft -hidetableheaders | gsutil -m cp -L log.log -r -n -I gs://bucket
```

But this only uploads the contents of the first folder in the list. I've tried using a foreach-object on the gsutil command, but I get an error due to not finding a URL to upload. When writing the output of the foreach to the console, the output appears to be completely empty.

I have confirmed that the entire line minus the gsutil command returns the correct folders from the path, so I know that the data is going into the pipeline. But I'm not sure why gsutil is only considering the first item in the pipeline.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance!

Comment: `... | ft -hidetableheaders | gsutil ...` -> `... | gsutil ...`

Comment: Do not use `Format-*` cmdlets unless you have a specific need to display formatted output *to a user*.

Comment: Thanks! gsutil still isn't uploading everything I want, but at least the script is a bit cleaner now :)

Comment: If it still copies just the first directory the parameter `-I` may not work as it should. Try `... | ForEach-Object { gsutil -m cp -n -r $_ gs://... }` instead.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Shame that the argument they put in doesn't work as expected, but there we go :)

Answer (score 0):

My `"c:\temp"` folder has two child folders. When I run `Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" | Where-Object {$_.psiscontainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | ft -hidetableheaders` Powershell does output the names of the two child folders in `c:\temp` to the console:

```
C:\temp\child folder A
C:\temp\child folder B
```

**However**, if you capture the output of the command and examine the data type of each path output, you'll see that they are **not strings**, and I think gsutil requires a string as input when using -I (I think `Ansgar Wiechers's` comment is correct)

Run this:

```
$x = Get-ChildItem "c:\temp"| Where-Object {$_.psiscontainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | ft -hidetableheaders 
write-host $x.Count
$x[0] | get-member
```

In my case, I see a count of 2 as expected (two child folders)

**However**, the datatype of the first item is not a string, it is a FormatEntryData:

`$x[0] | get-member`

shows the following on the console:

`TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData`

If you remove the `| ft -hidetableheaders` portion of your command, the data type of each item is  a string

Run this:

```
$x = Get-ChildItem "c:\temp"| Where-Object {$_.psiscontainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName 
write-host $x.Count
$x[0] | get-member
```

You'll see a data type of `TypeName: System.String` for `$x[0]`

Does this work with `gsutil`?

Comment: Hi Nova, thanks for the input! I may not have explained myself correctly in my original post, I don't need to search recursively though the path - I just need the gsutil command to to upload everything within that path.

If I have 2 or 3 Folders in Path, I expect all of those folders to be uploaded. But at the moment it is only uploading the first folder it finds.

Comment: @user3074653: I modified my answer. I think you need to trouble shoot each piece of your statements

Comment: Thanks Nova - as I said before, when I run those two Get-ChildItem commands without the gsutil command I return the list of all the folders I expect to see - and that includes the LastWriteTime condition. So I think the issue comes at the end of the statement, specifically with how gsutil is interpreting the contents of the pipe.

Comment: @user3074653: ok, one more time - see new answer. I think AnsGar had the answer

Answer (score 0):

As Ansgar Wiechers already said, do not use `Format-*` cmdlets unless you have a specific need to display formatted output to a user. If it still copies just the first directory the parameter -I may not work as it should. Try `... | ForEach-Object { gsutil -m cp -n -r $_ gs://... }` instead.